# Get corresponding elements from two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists test1 and test2. How to split the first two indexes into a separate lists

```
 test1 = [a,1,x]
 test2 = [b,2,y]
```

Final lists should be like this.

```
 first_alpha = [a,b]
 number = [1,2]
 last_alpha = [x,y]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip the lists and then unpack them into the target variables.

```
first_alpha, number, last_alpha = zip(test1, test2)
>>> first_alpha, number, last_alpha
(('a', 'b'), (1, 2), ('x', 'y'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [212]: test1 = ['a', 1, 'x']                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [213]: test2 = ['b', 2, 'y']                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [214]: for t in zip(test1, test2): print(list(t))                                                                                                                                                                                       
['a', 'b']
[1, 2]
['x', 'y']
```

Comment: Thanks. How to assign them to a variables?

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum `first_alpha, num, second_alpha = zip(test1, test2)`

Answer (score 0):

These other answers are awesome, i upvoted them, but i wanted to add one using your example exactly. Using your example exactly, you can do this:

```
 test1 = ['a',1,'x']
 test2 = ['b',2,'y']
```

Final lists should be like this.

```
 first_alpha = [test1[0], test2[0]]
 number = [test1[1], test2[1]]
 last_alpha = [test1[2], test2[2]]
```